# Netbook Windows 7 recovery after hard drive format

Tags: windows-7, netbook, partition-recovery, system-recovery

I have formatted hard drive on my netbook and deleted recovery partition.
Is it possible to recovery preinstalled Windows 7 after this?
(I have some problems with disc and this is the only way I found to make my netbook alive)

Is it possible to download Windows from Microsoft entering serial number or whatsoever?

Comment: Win7 download links...http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Answer (score 3):

Using the recovery disk is the best way but if they are not working, I guess you should contact your vendor. They will provide you another set of recovery discs at nominal or no cost!

Comment: Since you had recovery partition, I think getting a set of recovery disks from vendor is the best option. I'm not sure that the serial number which you have (if you have) will work. I havn't tried it but if you can download windows 7 iso, you must give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

If the computer had a recovery partition, it is likely the computer did not come with recovery discs.  Manufacturers are starting to do this more and more in order to cut down on costs. **And if you want recovery discs at this point, the manufacturer is probably going to charge you around $20 and then you have to wait a week to get them (or longer if they ship from overseas).**

You did not specify which version of Windows 7 you needed, but here are a few links directly from Microsoft. The files are ISO files which are images of DVDs.  Download them on another Windows 7 computer and use the built-in burning software to burn them to a DVD. If you're downloading them on an XP computer, you'll need something like UltraISO to burn them to a DVD. Make sure you have your Windows serial number (usually on the bottom of the laptop/netbook). You will be asked for this serial number during the installation process. Without this, these DVD ISOs are of no use to you. These links are to the OEM versions. They should work fine with the product key sticker that is attached to your computer by the manufacturer. The will not work for product keys that were bought via a retail channel (like a local electronics store). If you need a different version, leave a comment and I'll edit my post with more URLs.

[Windows 7 Starter N - 32bit](https://fp-pr1.ds.microsoft.com/TransferFile/FileTransfer.dll?Cmd=1&MN=2146337503&Dir=1&Mode=0&Off=0&TS=2E214138-901A-4DC1-B010-9FDD97DA1134&CVN=5,0,0,32)

[Windows 7 Home Premium - 32bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58996.iso)

[Windows 7 Home Premium - 64bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso)

[Windows 7 Professional - 32bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59183.iso)

[Windows 7 Professional - 64bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59186.iso)

[Windows 7 Ultimate - 32bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59463.iso)

[Windows 7 Ultimate - 64bit](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso)

Be aware however that this will only reinstall the operating system.  It will not reinstall any extra software that came preloaded on the computer from the manufacturer. Also, while Windows 7 is much better at automatically detecting drivers for computers, it is not guaranteed. You may need to download the drivers from the manufacturer's website for your particular computer and install them after you reinstall Windows. If this is the case and you have trouble finding them, provide your make and model number and I'll give you the link,